# IPv6 not working with vmbr0

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ipv6, bridge

Here are my configs:

Host:

```
> ip -6 route show dev vmbr0
2a01:4f8:141:54d8::/64 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

-

```
iface enp30s0 inet6 static
        address  2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2
        netmask  128
        gateway  fe80::1

iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address  2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2
        netmask  64
```

Guest:

```
> ip -6 route show dev ens19
2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2  metric 1024  pref medium
fe80::/64  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
default via 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2  metric 1024  pref medium
```

-

```
iface ens19 inet6 static
        address 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::3
        netmask 64
        gateway 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2
```

I can ping my host from my guest:

```
PING 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2(2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.110 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.120 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.120 ms
```

I can't ping google from my guest:

```
PING google.com(fra15s28-in-x0e.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
From fra15s28-in-x0e.1e100.net icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From fra15s28-in-x0e.1e100.net icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From fra15s28-in-x0e.1e100.net icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
From fra15s28-in-x0e.1e100.net icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address
```

I can ping google from my host:

```
PING google.com(fra16s07-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:816::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra16s07-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:816::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=5.33 ms
64 bytes from fra16s07-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:816::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=5.34 ms
64 bytes from fra16s07-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:816::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=5.32 ms
64 bytes from fra16s07-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:816::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=5.33 ms
```

I can't ping my guest from my host

```
PING 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::3(2a01:4f8:141:54d8::3) 56 data bytes
From 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2 icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2a01:4f8:141:54d8::2 icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

What I want:

Be able to reach both IPs from the www and reach the www from both IPs.

Comment: How many interface you have on the host ? can you try ping6 -I vmbr0 google.com ?

Comment: `ping6 -I vmbr0 google.com` gives `Network is unreachable`.

The host has 1 real interface, 2 bridges and many tap devices. The two interfaces you see above are the only ones with ipv6 config, the last bridge postroutes a private net.

Comment: how about ping -I vmbr0 google.com ?

Comment: Also not reachable. And yes, the bridge itself is working. All IPv4 traffic works.

Comment: can you check if ping -I vmbr0 8.8.8.8 works ? I dont see any ipv4 on vmbr0

Comment: Thats because I did not posted the IPv4 config.

iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  <main ip>
        netmask  255.255.255.255
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
        pre-up brctl addbr vmbr0
        up ip route add <one subnet ip>/32 dev vmbr0